# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>' How do I use a List<Dynamic> in a listview widget?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I am trying to use a list in a Listview widget in flutter but I keep getting an error saying that I need a List[Widget]. All the answers online make use of maps and I am still a beginner to Flutter. Can anyone show me how to use the map function for this or a way to convert List [Dynamic] to List [Widget]?

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NextPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List value;

  NextPage({Key key, this.value}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NextPageState createState() => new _NextPageState();
}

class _NextPageState extends State<NextPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Reminders"),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: widget.value,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `children: widget.value as List<Widget>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the discussion,  `value` is `List<String>` in that case, to pass it on `ListView` we need to use these data and convert them into widget.

Here we are using `value` and making `Text` widget with it

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NextPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> value;

  NextPage({Key key, this.value}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NextPageState createState() => new _NextPageState();
}

class _NextPageState extends State<NextPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Reminders"),
      ),
      body: ListView(
       children: widget.value.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Does it solve the issue?

Comment: That didn't seem to fix the problem, I'm still getting the same error

Comment: what are you passing as value, can you include that. also try `flutter clean` and run again.

Comment: does it solve or what errors you are currently getting?

Comment: When I use the type cast method the error says `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a  subtype of type 'List<Widget>' in type cast` I am passing in a list of strings that i recieve from an await function like this: `_remindersList = await _analyze(Words);`

Comment: ok you are just passing list of String at `NextPage`, am i right?

Comment: Yes I am with this: `new NextPage(value: _remindersList),`

Comment: in that case we need to use those string and convert them as Widget for ListView. let me update and  share a demo.

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to asking questions on stackoverflow, how do I do that?

Comment: I've updated the answer, does it solve the issue now?

Comment: Am I replacing NextPage with that or _NextPageState?

Comment: Just replace `children: widget.value,` with `widget.value.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),.` hope it will do the work.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to help you out.